# How to plot a row against columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following example DataFrame imported from Excel where columns = Months and rows = values for each month (essentially sales for each month):

```
  Jan 2017  Feb 2017 March 2017.......Dec 2017

0   10       15       12                13

1   2        4         5                 6
```

I would like to create a line chart with the date columns as the x axis and the values for each month as the y axis. This is easy to do in excel but with 50+ rows very time consuming.

Here's how I have attempted:

```
x = ['Jan 2017','Feb 2017', 'Mar 2017', 'Apr 2017', 'May 2017', 'Jun 2017', 'Jul 2017','Aug 2017', 'Sep 2017', 'Oct 2017', 'Nov 2017', 'Dec 2017']
y = Az.iloc[0]

plt.scatter(x,y, c='g')
plt.show()
```

Not really what I'm looking for...any suggestions on how to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Comment: hey @Mike, if you like my answer please accept it, or comment with what is not working. I've never had an accepted answer before so it would mean a lot to me. Thanks! Not good practice to just leave your question sitting like this...

Comment: Ok then @ Mike ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transpose your data so that it is "tidy" - each row should be a different date (observation), and each column should be a different type of data (e.g. counts of widget 1 vs widget 2).

Do something with Pandas dataframes reading in the data like:

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib notebook #use this line if you're working in a Jupyter notebook, or omit

df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
pretty_df=df.transpose()
pretty_df.plot()
```

If you post a part of the actual dataframe it would be easier to help.

Here's something that looks like it -

```
#Creating your dataset
x = ['Jan 2017','Feb 2017', 'Mar 2017', 'Apr 2017', 'May 2017', 'Jun 2017', 'Jul 2017','Aug 2017', 'Sep 2017', 'Oct 2017', 'Nov 2017', 'Dec 2017']
widget1 = pd.Series(np.random.random(len(x)))
widget2=pd.Series(np.random.random(len(x)))

df=pd.concat([widget1, widget2], axis=1)
df_like_your_problem=df.transpose()
df_like_your_problem.columns=x #this gets us to your starting point of ugly data. You would get here via pd.read_excel()

df_pretty=df_like_your_problem.transpose()
```

Creates a dataframe with dates as index:

```
Jan 2017  0.315193  0.626343
Feb 2017  0.525528  0.008994
Mar 2017  0.645849  0.272264
```

From there, it is fairly trivial to set the index to be a pandas DateTime object, and then use built in method of pandas plot (df_pretty.plot() ) to get what you need.